# Как билдить проект-расширение для браузера с vite?

Tags: chrome-extension, vite, manifest

Я предполагал такую структуру, я пишу проект в папке src а в браузер как расширение загружаю папку public куда должен буду билдить проект и добавлять ассеты. При этом файлик manifest.json изначально находиться в /public, вместе с popup.html(default_popup).

И всё же я столкнулся с проблемой, а не уверен точно где мне располагать default_popup, и с каких файлов идёт точка входа в приложение что указывается в rollupOptions в конфиге Vite, я там просто указал js файлы что использует manifest.json и popup.html.

Но главная проблема в том, что при таком подходе я не могу указать нормально главный забилдженный скрипт в manifest.json т.к. vite к их названию добавляет случайный хеш.

И так, где я допустил ошибку в проектировании проекта и билдинге, и как всё сделать по человечески? Или же всё более-менее правильно, и нужно просто найти своё решение этих проблем?